# Does the Mandelbrot set have infinite VC dimension?

Tags: computer-science, fractals, learning-theory

Define a binary classifier for points in the complex plane, whose parameter $\theta$ is an isometry of $\mathbb{C}$, and which classifies $z \in \mathbb{C}$ based on whether or not $\theta(z)$ is in the Mandelbrot set.

Two questions:

1. What is the [VC dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC_dimension) of this classifier? My intuition strongly says that it should be infinite.
2. Even more strongly, does this classifier shatter *all* finite sets of points if we also allow scaling in $\theta$ (that is, $\theta$ is a similarity)?

Comment: Here's a rephrasing of your question 2 (essentially unpacking the definition). Let $A$ and $B$ be two disjoint finite subsets of $\mathbb C$. Does there exist a similarity $\theta:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ of the complex plane such that $\theta(A)$ is contained in the Mandelbrot set, and $\theta(B)$ is contained in the complement of the Mandelbrot set?

Comment: I made a little numerical progress on this. By writing a [program](https://github.com/petersn/fractal-vc-dimension) that does blind brute-force search I found a set of 12 points that I could shatter, showing numerically that the VC dimension is at least 12. To get much beyond this I'll clearly need a less brute-force approach, though.

Comment: Good question. Since even a sinusoid, appropriately scaled and shifted, has infinite VC-dim, I would wager that so does the Mandelbrot set. I remain agnostic regarding the stronger claim.